# JSP SQL SERVER Connection

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jsp

**I am having below JSP page in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\webapp1 folder.**

**When I am trying to open this page in Google Chrome** http://localhost:7544/webapp1/DatabaseDB

**I am getting ERROR : localhost refused to connect.**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" errorPage="" %>
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>SELECT Operation</title>
       </head>
    <body>
    <%@ page import = "java.io.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.util.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "javax.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.sql.DriverManager" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.sql.ResultSet" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.sql.Connection" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.sql.Statement" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.sql.SQLException" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.sql.ClassNotFoundException" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.lang.System" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.lang.System.err" %>
    <%@ page import = "java.lang.System.exit" %>
    <%
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ASDFE;DatabaseName=PERSON","sa", "PWD");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TOP 1 PersonName FROM PersonDetails");

         %>
          <table border="1">
              <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
              </tr>
         <%
         while ( rs.next() ) {%>
            <tr><td><%=rs.getString("PersonName") %></td></tr>

          <% 
          }
          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close(); %>
          </table>
          <%
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                System.err.println(cnfe.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(2);
            }
    %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure the port is 7544?
2. Default port is 8080
3. Try http://localhost:8080/ first and see if the Tomcat home screen is showing.
4. Or try http://localhost:7544 if you are sure 7544 is correct
5. May be its: http://localhost:7544/webapp1/DatabaseDB.jsp (suffix .jsp missing)

Comment: Hi Rey Thanks for reply,I have tried using http://localhost:7544/webapp1/DatabaseDB.jsp. and port number is 7544 and now I am getting same error.

Comment: What do you see if you try 3) and 4)?

Comment: Hi Rey port number changed to 8080 default.Thanks